# Writing to resx file c#

Tags: c#, resources, resx

Trying to write to a Resx file written in xml.

How would i go about adding columns, and rows to it.

```
List<string> _paths = new List<string> { ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SpanPath"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FrenPath"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RusPath"] };

        ResourceWriter resourceWriter = new ResourceWriter(_paths.ElementAt(0));

        resourceWriter.AddResource("Key1", "String1");
        resourceWriter.AddResource("Key2", "String2");
        resourceWriter.Close();
```

I would like to add key1 and have the column beside it on that row to have string1 and so on.

I think I am not understanding how the msdn has explained the way the resource writer should be used.

Comment: I can't find "ResXResourceWriter" though anyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

Had to add reference from the solution explorer.
Add reference to System.Windows.Forms.

Then add System.Resources to top of class file.

Works now with ResXResourceWriter! :)

Answer (score 4):

You are missing the `resourceWriter.Generate()` call.

```
List<string> _paths = new List<string> { ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SpanPath"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FrenPath"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RusPath"] };

using(ResXResourceWriter resourceWriter = new ResXResourceWriter(_paths.ElementAt(0)))
{
    resourceWriter.AddResource("Key1", "String1");
    resourceWriter.AddResource("Key2", "String2");
    resourceWriter.Generate();
}
```

**Edit**. If you are losing the old keys you can store them in a hash table,add the new keys to the hash table and regenerate the resx from the hash table.

```
using System.Resources;

List<string> _paths = new List<string> { ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SpanPath"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FrenPath"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RusPath"] };

Hashtable oHt = new Hashtable();

// Read the keys and store in a hash table
using (ResXResourceReader oReader = new ResXResourceReader(_paths.ElementAt(0)))
{
     IDictionaryEnumerator oResource = oReader.GetEnumerator();
     while (oResource.MoveNext())
             oHt.Add(oResource.Key,oResource.Value);
}

//Add the new keys to the hash table
oHt["Key1"] = "String1";
oHt["Key2"] = "String2";

//Re-generate the new  resx from the hash table
using (ResXResourceWriter oWriter = new ResXResourceWriter(_paths.ElementAt(0)))
{
      foreach (string key in oHt.Keys)
           oWriter.AddResource(key.ToString(), oHt[key].ToString());
      oWriter.Generate();
}
```

Comment: but that removes all the xml and table thing that appears when the resx file is opened in VS. When the resx is opened, the file shows "ÎÊï¾   ‘   lSystem.Resources.ResourceReader, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089#System.Resources.RuntimeResourceSet          PADPADP —…|£—…|
       Þ   K e y 1     K e y 2     String1String2"

Comment: Save the old keys in a hashtable,add the keys to hash table and write all the keys from hash table to the resx

Comment: Sorry, maybe it's because i'm using resourcewriter instead of ResXResourceWriter? I can't find the namespace for ResXResourceWriter though? 
Oh and I don't know how to do that, your last comment. :)

Comment: Find my own solution which worked! Upvoted yours for help anyhow! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The methods you are calling are indeed correct and the way that MSDN has advised.

The parameter you pass into the constructor for `ResourceWriter` is the path at where you would like the resource file to be stored including the filename.

Either relative (just the file name `"myStrings.resources"`) or absolute (full file path `"C:\\Users\\Folder\\myStrings.resources"`) can be used. *More on the `\\` in a moment...*

I don't know what value your first `_paths` element is, but be sure that it is properly formed for where you would like the file to be stored. *If you could let me know what your `_paths.AtElement(0)` string is; I could perhaps help further.*

**PLEASE NOTE** If you are using an absolute file path, ensure that your `\` in your everyday "C:\Users\User1\AFolder" location (from Windows file browser) are escaped; this is done by placing `\` in front.

So, for example a folder `C:\Users\User1\AFolder` should actually be escaped and written in a string like `"C:\\Users\\User1\\AFolder"`.

**EQUALLY AS IMPORTANT** Make sure you use `using` as the `IResourceWriter` class implements `IDisposable`.

Do this by wrapping your code in a using statement:

```
using (ResourceWriter resourceWriter = new ResourceWriter(_paths.ElementAt(0))
{
    resourceWriter.AddResource("Key1", "String1");
    resourceWriter.AddResource("Key2", "String2");
    resourceWriter.Close();
}
```

This is good practice to use `using` where an `IDisposable` derivative is used.

Hope this helps!